# Radare2's equivalent of GDB's Radare2's equivalent of GDB's set $reg 0x2020

Tags: radare2

I would really like to change the registers during radare2's debugging sessiong. In GDB,

```
set $reg 0x2020
```

was very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: In radare2, while debugging, you use `dr <register>=<val>`

Use the -d flag to begin Radare2 in debugging mode

```
r2 -d /usr/bin
```

You'll have a prompt in front of you, type v and then p a few times to get to the debugging view.

Press colon to enter commands. You'll most likely want to analyze the binary. To do this, press colon and then `aaa` or `aa`. Note, that `aaa` does could take more time, but does performs a more in-depth analysis.

Once in debugging mode, use db [address] to set a breakpoint. For example, to set a breakpoint at main

```
db main
```

And you can get to main, enter `s main`. This jumps to main (s is for seek).

Then, if you want to change the register `rdi`

```
dr rdi=0x20
```

For more register options, see: https://r2wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options/d/dr/